# Screen backlight control for Asus G55V

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness, asus

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an Asus G55V laptop and neither the laptop brightness control keys (`FN`+`F5`, `FN`+`F6`) nor the Brightness setting are able to control the backlight.

Note that I've installed the `nvidia-current` driver, as the laptop is equiped with a GeForce GTX 660M, and it's working fine.

So far here is what have tried to no avail:

- Switch to a console (`Alt`+`F1`) and use the laptop brightness control keys (this method was working with 10.04 and Lenovo T410),
- `echo 2 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`,
- Added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` to `/etc/default/grub` and updated Grub config,
- Also tried without `acpi_osi=Linux`.

Out of all these attempts, one thing changed: if I change the brightness in the BIOS bootloader right before booting on the HDD, the brightness setting stays the same in Ubuntu. This is an acceptable temporary workaround but I would really like to be able to control the backlight brightness from Ubuntu (can be from command line, fine with me).

Any suggestions on what to try next would be highly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to run the second command `echo 2 > ..` successfully? What is output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`

Comment: Yes, the command was working before I tried the Grub change but wasn't changing the backlight intensity. Currently, the output of the `ls` command you asked is `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Removed `acpi_backlight=vendor` from grub and re-run the `ls` command which now gives `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. Echoing numbers to it produces no error but also no brightness change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with: https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl

#### Installation

```
wget https://github.com/downloads/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/nvidiabl-dkms_0.76_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i nvidiabl-dkms_0.76_all.deb
sudo modprobe nvidiabl
```

#### Print current brightness value

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight/actual_brightness
```

#### Print maximun brightness value

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight/max_brightness
```

#### Adjust brightness

```
echo 50 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: Things go fine until `sudo modprobe nvidiabl` which dies with `FATAL: Error inserting nvidiabl (/lib/modules/3.2.0-25-generic-pae/updates/dkms/nvidiabl.ko): No such device`.

Comment: Same error occurs even after removing `acpi_backlight=vendor` from grub.

Comment: Seems that your device isn't recognized by nvidiabl, and it is expected if you have a really new hardware. I suggest you to open a ticket at https://github.com/guillaumezin/nvidiabl/issues reporting your hardware spec. For geeky users, it is possible to debug driver by himself as explained in the README.

Comment: Works fine with version 0.76 of the package! I updated your answer to show this version for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: FTR: Version 0.87 works great with 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

try to execute the following command:

> /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness **3**

replace **3** with something between 0 and **max-brightness**. You can find out what **max-brightness** is by running following command:

> /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-max-brightness

Comment: Using `gsd-backlight-helper` returns `** (gsd-backlight-helper:3040): WARNING **: failed to find any devices`.

Comment: After removing `acpi_backlight=vendor` from grub, the commands run. Max brightess returns `10` and set-brigthness returns no error but doesn't change the backlight brightness.

Comment: sorry pal... worked for me, when other suggestions did not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me, the only thing that does not work is the FN + F8 or F9. I wonder if I can fix this ? All the other FN combinations work properly. I'm on a custom computer  Clevo W370ET with nvidia gtx660m

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Asus P50IJ notebook and Ubuntu 14.04. After i add the kernel boot parameter "acpi_backlight=vendor" the function keys works again.

You can use this command:

```
 sudo sed -i 's|quiet splash|acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash|g' /etc/default/grub
 sudo update-grub
```

Don´t forget to reboot you notebook after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys)
It just might work as long as the keys are ACPI ones...
Personally, I still get: "failed to find any devices"
but still working on it...

Comment: It is preferable if a summary is posted here and the link provided for further reference. Answers with just links are not encouraged on Ask Ubuntu